# Access audit logs in Google Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

How can we access the audit logs in Bigtable (for instance, to know who dropped a table, or who altered some columns...) ?

I've checked in "Stackdriver logging" where I can see all the Google Cloud components but BigTable.

Or is it available with a "gcloud beta logging" option?

Comment: Bigtable now supports admin activity audit logging, which is what you're asking about: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/audit-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am the product manager for Google Cloud Bigtable.*

On 21 Dec 2017, we added support for [Cloud Bigtable Admin activity audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/audit-logging), so now you will be able to see when someone created or dropped a table; created, updated, or deleted a column family, etc.